# To make a new method in a class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

Hey guys!
I'm new to Java, and I want to make a new class called Student. Now I want every student to have their own grade array. My question is: how do I make a method setGradeArray in the class Student?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Student
{
    private int[] gradeArray;
    public void setGradeArray(int[] value)
    {
        this.gradeArray = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Big +1 on your solution. Very clean ;)